# how to use ln in Java

Tags: java, math, function

I'm trying to use this formula in JAVA :  **(-ln(1-L))/L**

I'm not sure how to use ln in java.

Comment: If you're a math guy looking at CS, be wary of floating point calculations. Depending on how you craft and estimate your formulas, you'll wind up with different amounts of error due to how floating point math is handled internally. If you want fixed-width precision to some high amount, you'll want to look into other math libraries that `java.lang.Math`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`Math.log(d)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29) returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value.

So the java code will be,

```
double result = (-Math.log(1-L))/L;
```

(but note that it's better to have variable names in lower-case - i.e. `l` instead of `L`)

Comment: thank you! I have an extra question..how do I round up a number in java (in C was fairly easy) for example I have this number 22.0363456586776, but I want to display 22.036345659

Comment: In general, use DecimalFormat: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html  If you have a specific issue, feel free to post it as a separate question.

Comment: For conversion to a string you can use String.format(), e.g. String.format("%.10f", x), for printing System.out.printf().

Answer (score 5):

I also had no idea, but since it's a common math function, I checked the [Math class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/).

Here you go: [the log method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log(double))

EDIT: Sorry for broken link, Markdown is fixed now.  Also I realized right after I posted this answer that it sounds snarky, which was not my intent; re-wordings just make it seems snarky AND sarcastic, though.  I just wanted to make the point that the API really is useful for methods that could be reasonably expected to come up a lot.

Comment: I think -log1p(-L)/L might be more accurate for small L.

Comment: Good point.  @fang, are you using a large or small value for L?

Comment: thats the formula they gave me.

Comment: I guess I better use "ln" as given, but thanks guys you are awesome!