# How to make LN (Log Natural) function?

Tags: java, android, math, regression, exponential

I want to make a simple math project to count Exponential regression. How to make LN (Log Natural) function in Android Studio?

Comment: What's wrong with `Math.log(x)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use ln in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568142/how-to-use-ln-in-java)

Comment: Log(2) and Ln(2) has different answers @Sweeper

Comment: In Math, yes. But in Java, `Math.log` is the ln function. Try printing out `Math.log(Math.E)`. You'll get 1.0, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`ln` is just log to the base `e`. The `java.lang.Math` class has this handy method called [`log`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-).

According to the docs,

> Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value.

The "Returns:" section says this even more clearly:

> Returns:
>
> the value ln a, the natural logarithm of a.

Which is exactly what you want.